# Using headers with the Python requests library's get method

Tags: python, http-request, python-requests

So I recently stumbled upon this great library for handling HTTP requests in Python; found here http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html.

I love working with it, but I can't figure out how to add headers to my get requests. Help?

Answer (score 578, accepted):

According to the [API](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/), the headers can all be passed in with `requests.get()`:

```
import requests
r=requests.get("http://www.example.com/", headers={"Content-Type":"text"})
```

Comment: You can check the http request header sent doing : print(r.request.headers)

Answer (score 67):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36634227/819417) taught me that you can set headers for an entire session:

```
s = requests.Session()
s.auth = ('user', 'pass')
s.headers.update({'x-test': 'true'})

# both 'x-test' and 'x-test2' are sent
s.get('http://httpbin.org/headers', headers={'x-test2': 'true'})
```

Bonus: [Sessions also handle cookies.](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects)

Answer (score 57):

Seems pretty straightforward, according to the [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/) on the page you linked (emphasis mine).

> requests.get(url, params=None, headers=None, cookies=None, auth=None,
>   timeout=None)
>
> Sends a GET request.
>   Returns `Response` object.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - url – URL for the new
>     `Request` object.
> - params – (optional)
>     Dictionary of GET Parameters to send
>     with the `Request`.
> - **headers – (optional)
>     Dictionary of HTTP Headers to send
>     with the `Request`.**
> - cookies – (optional)
>     CookieJar object to send with the
>     `Request`.
> - auth – (optional) AuthObject
>     to enable Basic HTTP Auth.
> - timeout –
>     (optional) Float describing the
>     timeout of the request.

Answer (score 16):

1. Go to http://myhttpheader.com
2. copy attributes - typically 'Accept-Language' and 'User-Agent'.
3. Wrap them in the dictionary:

   ```py
   headers = { 'Accept-Language' : content-copied-from-myhttpheader,
               'User-Agent':content-copied-from-myhttpheader}
   ```
4. pass headers in your request

   ```py
   requests.get(url=your_url,headers=headers)
   ```