# Django creating/making POST request with headers

Tags: django, http-headers, http-post, google-url-shortener

I want to make a POST request programmatically with a custom headers. How can I do that?

Actually i am trying to do [this](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#shorten); use google shortener api. Maybe i misunderstood :/

Thanks you in advance :)

Comment: Have you got some code?

Comment: `data = {"longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"}`
`urllib.urlopen(api_url, data)`
But here there is no headers. There is a class `urllib2.Request` found now, trying to use it :)

Comment: Please read mi answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To send an POST request with Python and with headers you can do something like

```
import urllib2
import json
data = {'data':'data'}
url = api_url
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
request = urllib2.Request(url, data=json.dumps(data))
request.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json") #Header, Value                                        
opener.open(request)
```

Comment: Thank you :) but need a little change, this works when you make `data` json; `request = urllib2.Request(url, data=json.dumps(data))`

Comment: It's only an example you can add some diferent header

Answer (score 14):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206843/django-creating-making-post-request-with-headers/17207107?noredirect=1#17207107) working great. But found another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8685813/1023930);

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url'
data = {'longUrl': 'http://www.google.com/'}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

then

```
answer = json.loads(r.text)
```

or

```
answer = r.json()
```

Here is `requests` package; [code](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) and [doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Yes also requests is a great library

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import requests
def short_url(url):
    post_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key={API_KEY}'
    params = json.dumps({'longUrl': url})
    response = requests.post(post_url,params,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    return response.json()['id']
```