# How to add header in requests

Tags: python, python-requests

Is there any other elegant way to add header to requests :

```
import requests

requests.get(url,headers={'Authorization', 'GoogleLogin auth=%s' % authorization_token})
```

doesn't work, while urllib2 worked :

```
import urllib2

request = urllib2.Request('http://maps.google.com/maps/feeds/maps/default/full')
request.add_header('Authorization', 'GoogleLogin auth=%s' % authorization_token)
urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

Comment: that's not dictionary syntax at all...

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685790/adding-header-to-python-request-module) answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using headers with the Python requests library's get method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260457/using-headers-with-the-python-requests-librarys-get-method)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding header to python request module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685790/adding-header-to-python-request-module)

Answer (score 17):

**You can add headers by passing a dictionary as an argument.**

This should work:

```
requests.get(url,headers={'Authorization': 'GoogleLogin auth=%s' % authorization_token})
```

**Why your code not worked?**

You were **not passing a dictionary** to the headers argument. You were passing values according to the format defined in `add_header()` function.

According to docs,

> requests.get(url, params=None, headers=None, cookies=None, auth=None,
>   timeout=None)
>
> headers – (optional) Dictionary of HTTP Headers to send with the
>   Request.

**Why request.add_header() worked?**

Your way of adding headers using `request.add_header()`worked because the function is defined as such in the `urllib2` module.

> ```
> Request.add_header(key, val)
> ```

It accepts two arguments -

1. Header name (key of dict defined earlier)
2. Header value(value of the corresponding key in the  dict defined earlier)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass dictionary through `headers` keyword. This is very elegant in Python :-)

```
 headers = {
     "header_name": "header_value",
 }

 requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom headers to a requests request using the following format which uses a Python dictionary having a colon, `:`, in its syntax.

```
r = requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'GoogleLogin auth=%s' % authorization_token})
```

This is presented in the [Requests documentation for custom headers](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) as follows:

```
>>> url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
>>> headers = {'user-agent': 'my-app/0.0.1'}

>>> r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

Headers should be a dict, thus this should work

```
headers= {}
headers['Authorization']= 'GoogleLogin auth=%s' % authorization_token

requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```