# Slow code using selenium and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to fetch data using selenium webdriver and beautiful soup from a website. Below segment of code is taking a long time to execute.

```
time1 = time.time()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.bseindia.com/")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("suggestBoxEQ")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("538707")  
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
print(driver.current_url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
driver.quit()
time2 = time.time()
print(time2-time1)
```

It takes `13.876`seconds to execute this code. Is there any way to speed up execution time of current code or another faster method to get fetch the data?

Comment: What data do you want to scrape? Entering the number redirects to this URL: https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/rajasthan-cylinders--containers-ltd/rccl/538707/

Comment: I need to get "Trade Date, Quantity Traded, Deliverable Quantity, % of Deliverable Quantity to Traded Quantity, market cap, security ID " etc for a company listed in BSE. TO achieve this I am getting dynamic content of the page using selenium and the processing it using beautifulsoup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After entering *538707* on [this URL](https://www.bseindia.com/), the page redirects to [this URL](https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/rajasthan-cylinders--containers-ltd/rccl/538707/).

The tables and other data on this page are loaded from AJAX requests. You can directly get data from these requests for scraping. To see the AJAX requests, go the XHR tab under the Network tab in Developer tools and refresh the page. You can get data from the XHR requests you see here.

For example, the table *Securitywise Delivery Position* is loaded from [this URL](https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/SiteCache/SecurityPosition.aspx?Type=EQ&text=538707). So, you can directly get the table like this:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/SiteCache/SecurityPosition.aspx?Type=EQ&text=538707')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table')
```

Scrape this table using BeautifulSoup. For example:

```
print(table.find('td', class_='newseoscripfig').text)
# 13 Apr 2018
```

Similarly, you can find nearly all the data that is loaded dynamically in other
XHR requests. As Selenium is not used here, the script is pretty fast.

Comment: Keyur, I am unable to get data for some tables like "Stock Trading", "Market Depth" using XHR.  https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/SiteCache/Stock_Trading.aspx?text=538707&type=EQ , https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/SiteCache/Stock_Trading.aspx?text=538707&type=EQ

Comment: It seems that [this url](https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/SiteCache/Stock_Trading.aspx?text=538707&type=EQ) needs headers to make the request. Use the headers that are shown in the *Request Headers*. [This Q/A on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260457/using-headers-with-the-python-requests-librarys-get-method) might help you to do that. [This too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685790/adding-header-to-python-request-module/36634227#36634227).

Comment: In this answer I've shown you the general idea to scrape all the dynamic elements. If you have any more problems regarding a specific XHR, I think you should ask a new question for that. If I add those things in this answer, it'll become a bit broad and out of scope.

Comment: Sure, I will ask a new question. XHR is really fast compared to selenium.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, I always send header along with requests. I don't want my self blocked :P

Comment: No, It didn't work. If it requires header then it should get data in browser. Brower will be sending header information.

Comment: I got the response after I added the *Referer* header. And no, if you copy and open the link on another tab, you won't see the data if other headers like referer, origin, etc are required.

Comment: r = requests.get('https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/SiteCache/Stock_Trading.aspx?text=538707&type=EQ', headers=header)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    print(soup) ## I am using fake user agent. It returns no data

Comment: I am getting data in r. Mean server is sending data. But soup object is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169035/discussion-between-keyur-potdar-and-yadav).