# Convert this curl command to Python 3

Tags: python, http, curl, request

How can I send this curl out using Python?
I did find similar requests, but cannot adapt my code to suite the query
I have also tried using `pycurl`, following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491090/how-to-use-python-to-execute-a-curl-command?lq=1) but without luck.

```
$ curl -v -X GET  -H "Accept: text/csv" -H "Authorization: Basic YW5kcmVhLmJvdHRpQHdzcC5jb206OWY5N2E5YTY2ZWU1MTMxZjdmNjk4MDcwZTFkODEwMjU0M2I0NTg1ZA==" "https://epc.opendatacommunities.org/api/v1/domestic/search"
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding header to python requests module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685790/adding-header-to-python-requests-module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the [Python Requests package](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) the following code snippet should work:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/csv',
    'Authorization': 'Basic YW5kcmVhLmJvdHRpQHdzcC5jb206OWY5N2E5YTY2ZWU1MTMxZjdmNjk4MDcwZTFkODEwMjU0M2I0NTg1ZA==',
}

response = requests.get('https://epc.opendatacommunities.org/api/v1/domestic/search', headers=headers)

response.status_code  # 200
response.text # "lmk-key,address1,address2,address3,postcode,buildi ..."
```

(Note: I used the https://curl.trillworks.com/ website to automatically make the conversion)