# unable to get the output of a web link in a python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fetch the data from a link to a pandas dataframe using request, but unable to get the same. Need help:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/getHistoricalData.jsp?symbol=ZEEL&series=EQ&fromDate=undefined&toDate=undefined&datePeriod=3months"

data = requests.get(url)

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the request.get returns a response object. You need to parse the Response using the library BeautifulSoup or lxml.

Also, you need to attach a valid header otherwise server terminates the request refer to below links-

[adding header to python requests module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685790/adding-header-to-python-requests-module)

[How to use Python requests to fake a browser visit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652543/how-to-use-python-requests-to-fake-a-browser-visit)

If you are just looking to get the data somehow, you can run it using selenium(below code works) although 
THIS CAN BE HANDLED WITH REQUEST.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
webpage = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/getHistoricalData.jsp?symbol=ZEEL&series=EQ&fromDate=undefined&toDate=undefined&datePeriod=3months'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='Your/path/to/chromedriver.exe') 
driver.get(webpage)

html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('table')
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

res = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in td if tr.text.strip()]
    if row:
        res.append(row)


df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=["Date", "Symbol", "Series", "Open Price","High Price","Low Price","Last Traded Price ","Close Price","Total Traded Quantity","Turnover (in Lakhs)"])
print(df)
driver.quit()
```