# Weird encoding file format outputted by BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I would like to access and scrape the data from this [link](https://www.scopus.com/results/results.uri?sort=plf-f&src=s&imp=t&sid=2c816e0ea43cf176a59117097216e6d4&sot=b&sdt=b&sl=160&s=%28TITLE-ABS-KEY%28EEG%29AND%20TITLE-ABS-KEY%28%22deep%20learning%22%29%20AND%20DOCTYPE%28ar%29%29%20AND%20ORIG-LOAD-DATE%20AFT%201591735287%20AND%20ORIG-LOAD-DATE%20BEF%201592340145%20%20AND%20PUBYEAR%20AFT%202018&origin=CompleteResultsEmailAlert&dgcid=raven_sc_search_en_us_email&txGid=cc4809850a0eff92f629c95380f9f883).

where;

```
new_url='https://www.scopus.com/results/results.uri?sort=plf-f&src=s&imp=t&sid=2c816e0ea43cf176a59117097216e6d4&sot=b&sdt=b&sl=160&s=%28TITLE-ABS-KEY%28EEG%29AND+TITLE-ABS-KEY%28%22deep+learning%22%29+AND+DOCTYPE%28ar%29%29+AND+ORIG-LOAD-DATE+AFT+1591735287+AND+ORIG-LOAD-DATE+BEF+1592340145++AND+PUBYEAR+AFT+2018&origin=CompleteResultsEmailAlert&dgcid=raven_sc_search_en_us_email&txGid=cc4809850a0eff92f629c95380f9f883'
```

As accessing the `new_url` via the following line

```
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.9'})
```

produced the error

```
Webscraping: HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop
```

A set of new line was drafted

```
req = urllib.request.Request(new_url, None, {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; G518Rco3Yp0uLV40Lcc9hAzC1BOROTJADjicLjOmlr4=) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36','Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8','Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8','Connection': 'keep-alive'})
cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
raw = opener.open(req).read()

page_soup = soup(raw, 'html.parser')
print(page_soup.prettify())
```

While no error is thrown out, but the

```
print(page_soup.prettify())
```

output some unrecognized text format

> 6�>�.�t1k�e�LH�.��]WO�?m�^@�
> څ��#�h[>��!�H8����|����n(XbU<~�k�"���#g+�4�Ǻ�Xv�7�UȢB2�
> �7�F8�XA��W\�ɚ��^8w��38�@'
> SH�<_0�B���oy�5Bނ)E���GPq:�ќU�c���ab�h�$<ra�
> ;o�Q�a@ð�d\�&J3Τa*�����:�I�etf�a���h�*$(M�~���ua�$�
> n�&9u%ҵ*b���w�j�V��P�D�'z[��������)

with a warning

```
Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.
```

I suspect, this can be resolved by encode it using `utf-8`, which is as below

```
req = urllib.request.Request(new_url, None, {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; G518Rco3Yp0uLV40Lcc9hAzC1BOROTJADjicLjOmlr4=) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36','Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8','Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8','Connection': 'keep-alive'})
cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
raw = opener.open(req).read()
with open(raw, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    page_soup = soup(f, 'html.parser')
    print(page_soup.prettify())
```

However, the compiler return an error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position
> 1: invalid start byte

May I know what is the problem, appreciate for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `urllib` library, remove `Accept-Encoding` from the headers (also specify `Accept-Charset` just `utf-8` for simplicity):

```
req = urllib.request.Request(new_url, None, {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; G518Rco3Yp0uLV40Lcc9hAzC1BOROTJADjicLjOmlr4=) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36','Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8','Accept-Charset': 'utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8','Connection': 'keep-alive'})
```

The result is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--  Form Name: START -->
<html lang="en">
 <!-- Template_Component_Name: id.start.vm -->
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>

...etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It works. But,it seems Scopus restrict user from accessing their website via non-browser approach despite using our institution connection. Accessing the above url stop at the Scopus main landing page.

Comment: Apologies for the -1, it wasn't on purpose and I can't undo it now for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Try using the requests library

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36"}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(new_url, headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.get_text())
```

you can still use cookies here

Edit: Updated code to show the use of headers, this would tell the website you are a browser instead of a program - but further login operations I would suggest the use of selenium instead of requests

Comment: Thanks for the response @thf9527, may I know how to enable cookies? Apparently the website Denied Access. It seem they know I am accessing using non conventional browser

Comment: Include a "User-Agent" header for the get request should get you to the login page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260457/using-headers-with-the-python-requests-librarys-get-method

Comment: I would recommend selenium instead of requests for your login operation as it seems to involve javascript.