# not getting a urllib response on some urls that opens regularly in the webbrowser

Tags: python, urllib, urllib3

I am having an issue with urllib on python3 that I dont know how to solve.
this is my code :

```
import urllib.request
       hdr = { 'User-Agent' : 'super happy flair bot by /u/spladug' }
       req = urllib.request.Request(url,headers=hdr)
       data = urllib.request.urlopen(req,timeout=10).read()
       return data
```

Stuff I tried:

1. Changing user agent
2. Adding and removing timeouts
3. curl these sites

but still there are some sites(that ends with image file extension like http://xxx.xxx/aaa.png or .jpg) that I just can't get a response,
and if I am setting a timeout I am getting TimeOutError. but if i open the same site in the chrome everything working fine.
Does someone have any solution or faced the issue?

site example -
https://sgfm.elcorteingles.es/SGFM/dctm/MEDIA03/202006/24/00117731276964____5__210x210.jpg

Comment: It's going to be tough for anyone to troubleshoot this without at least one example of a URL that causes the problem. Try to post code problems as reproducible examples: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @CrazyChunky whoops ,forgot to add the site example https://sgfm.elcorteingles.es/SGFM/dctm/MEDIA03/202006/24/00117731276964____5__210x210.jpg

Comment: getting this message UP

Comment: I don't have a solution, but things to add to the "doesn't work" pile: copying the entire set of headers sent by Chrome when successfully accessing the URL, checking to see if there's a redirect going on (there isn't), and running `curl` with `-k` just in case there's some kind of SSL error. (And trying `requests` too, though I see you mentioned that in your commend on Andrej's answer.) I don't know why it's not working, but if you edit your question with more detail on what's *not* working, it might help draw the right person's eye.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's the error in your code, but I'm using `requests` and I never had that problem.

```
import requests
response=requests.get(URL)
print(response.text)
```

How to use Headers in requests .get():
[Using headers with the Python requests library's get method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260457/using-headers-with-the-python-requests-librarys-get-method)

Comment: I dont recieve any error, since I don't even get the response. I know how to use requests and urllib ,It's just some specific sites that not working