# Freedom of information act API. API key error

Tags: python

I am having some trouble running the Freedom of information act API in python. I am sure it is related to how I am implementing my API key but I am uncertain as to where I am dropping the ball. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import requests

apikey= ''

api_base_url = f"https://api.foia.gov/api/webform/submit"
endpoint = f"{api_base_url}{apikey}"
r = requests.get(endpoint)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

there  error I receive is  requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for this website. Thanks again

Comment: no it doesn't. Thank you for correcting that error. I still get a 403 error after removing it

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://www.foia.gov/developer/#submission), you should be providing your API key via the `X-API-Key` header, not as part of the request URL.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you can make a `GET` request against that endpoint. But I haven't read the spec closely enough to be sure on that point.

Comment: @larsks - There are examples of GET requests in the documentation ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.foia.gov/developer/), the API requires the API key to be passed as a request header parameter ("X-API-Key").  Your python code appears to be simply concatenating the API key and the URL.

The following Q&A explains how to set a request header using `requests`.

- [Using headers with the Python requests library's get method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260457/using-headers-with-the-python-requests-librarys-get-method)

It would be something like this:

```
import requests

apikey= ...
api_base_url = ...
r = requests.get(api_base_url, 
                 headers={"X-API-Key": apikey})

print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

Note that the documentation for the FOIA site explains what you need to do to submit a FIOA request form.  It is significantly different to what your Python code is apparently trying to do.  I would advise you to *read the documentation*.  Also read the manual entry for the "curl" command so that you understand the requests that the examples show.

Comment: Thanks you! that really helps it.