# send a post request to a website with multiple form tags using requests in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

good evening,
im trying to write a programme that extracts the sell price of certain stocks and shares on a website called hl.co.uk
As you can imagine you have to search for the stock you want to see the sale price of.
my code so far is as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = "https://www.hl.co.uk/shares"

page = requests.get(url)
parsed_html = soup(page.content, 'html.parser')
form = parsed_html.find('form', id="stock_search")
input_tag = form.find('input').get('name')
submit = form.find('input', id="stock_search_submit").get('alt')

post_data = {input_tag: "fgt", "alt": submit}
```

i have been able to extract the correct form tag and the input names i require. but the website has multiple forms on this page.

how can i submit a post request to this website using the data i have in "post_data" to that specfic form in order for it to search the stockk/share that i desire and then give me the next page?

thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe look at Selenium ? https://realpython.com/modern-web-automation-with-python-and-selenium/

Comment: You can use `headers` argument as in [using headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260457/using-headers-with-the-python-requests-librarys-get-method)

Comment: What have you tried? The 3rd line of example code in the requests [quickstart](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/) shows doing a post with data, did you try that? Did it not work for you?

Comment: thank you all for the suggestions ill have a look into these. @Macattack i wont lie, i didnt really try anything i just had a massive brain fart and didnt even no where to begin. ive wrote code previously to submit form data but never to a page with multiple forms

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty general problem which you can use google chrome's devtools to solve. Basically,

1- Navigate to the page where you have a form and bunch of fields.

In your case page should look like this:
[image]

2- Then choose **XHR** tab under **Network** tab which will filter out all Fetch and XHR requests. These requests are generally sent after a form submission and they return a JSON with resulting data most of the time.

3- Make sure you enable the checkbox on the top left **Preserve Log** so the list doesn't refresh when form is submitted.

4- Submit the form, then you'll see bunch of requests are being made. Inspect them to hopefully find what you're looking for.

In this case I found this URL endpoint which gives out the results as response.

> https://www.hl.co.uk/ajax/funds/fund-search/search?investment=&companyid=1324&sectorid=132&wealth=&unitTypePref=&tracker=&payment_frequency=&payment_type=&yield=&standard_ocf=&perf12m=&perf36m=&perf60m=&fund_size=&num_holdings=&start=0&rpp=20&lo=0&sort=fd.full_description&sort_dir=asc&

You can see all the query parameters here as **companyid, sectorid** what you need to do is change those and just make a request to URL. Then you'll get the relevant information.

To retrieve those **companyid** and **sectorid** values you can send a get request to the page https://www.hl.co.uk/shares/search-for-investments?stock_search_input=ftg&x=17&y=23&category_list=CEHGINOPW which has those dropdowns and filter the html to find these values in the screenshot below:

You can see this documentation for BS4 to find tags inside HTML source, https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer this is helpful in many way. however, might seem like a daft quesion but where you've mentioned companyid and sectorid both are numbers realted to what i assume is the company. how would i find the relevant ID's?

Comment: Ah, I think the way to find the IDs can be done by retrieving the html of <select> tags, if you go to the form's page and right click on dropwon then click Inspect, you can see that each value under <optgroup> has company names and IDs as "value" attribute. You can save or print out those values by using BeautifulSoup like you did in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you submit the form from the homepage, it redirect you to the the target page with an url looking like this, "https://www.hl.co.uk/shares/search-for-investments?stock_search_input=abc&x=56&y=35&category_list=CEHGINOPW", so in my opinion, instead of submitting the homepage form, you should directly call the target page with your own GET parameters, the url you're supposed to call will look like this [https://www.hl.co.uk/shares/search-for-investments?stock_search_input=[your_keywords]](https://www.hl.co.uk/shares/search-for-investments?stock_search_input=%5Byour_keywords%5D).
Hope this helped you

Comment: Good idea that is, would make it much simpler. ill give it a bash and let you know