# Remote end closed connection without response

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to get the HTML source from a webpage using the following code:

```
import requests
url = "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english-arabic/hi"
r = requests.get(url)
```

but, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/ak_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/username/ak_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/home/username/ak_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 276, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/ak_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/home/username/ak_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/username/ak_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 532, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/username/ak_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/username/ak_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/username/ak_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/home/username/ak_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 276, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/username/ak_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/ak_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/ak_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/username/ak_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/ak_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

Is there any way to fix this issue? any other function to get the source code?
I used wget and it works. I may consider using wget to download the page if there is no direct fix or another python function.

Comment: They may be seeing your request as illegitimate and dropping it. Try changing the user agent string.

Comment: Thanks @Carcigenicate, I changed the user agent and it worked

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are missing headers to authenticate yourself as a User.

This one will help you:

```
import requests

url = 'https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english-arabic/hi'

headers = requests.utils.default_headers()

headers.update(
    {
        'User-Agent': 'My User Agent 1.0',
    }
)

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

It works on my machine.  Some more information according to headers:

- [Sending "User-agent" using Requests library in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606133/sending-user-agent-using-requests-library-in-python)
- [Using headers with the Python requests library's get method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260457/using-headers-with-the-python-requests-librarys-get-method)