# Making a http request using a session token to log in a website on python

Tags: python, request, session-cookies

Firstly, the objective is to make a http request every certain time, but there is a problem: the login screen.

In short, i tried to make a request to the link firefaucet.win/start with this code below

```
import requests    
requests.get('https://firefaucet.win/start')
```

This request returns to the login page, because to use this website you need to have a account.
 Doing by the common way, making a POST request with the auth is out of question, because the login is followed by a captcha box. I figured out another way to log in, that is using my own session token, that i got on the cookies of my browser. But this is the point, I don't know how to log in using just the session token.

Comment: Try and set `Cookie` header for a request? [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260457/using-headers-with-the-python-requests-librarys-get-method)

Comment: reading this link i will try more things that i thought tomorrow

Comment: update: reading the docs i've done what i wanted to, and i answered my own question and added the solution code on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read a lot on the [requests lib docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and the answer is just make a request session object and make the request using the cookies kwarg, that is default to None. Just by reading that the session token is kept in a cookie named "session" on the browser, I achieved the objective just by putting the session token inside the "session" cookie like the code below:

```
import requests
obj = requests.Session()
response = obj.request(
    'get', 
    'https://firefaucet.win/start',
    cookies={
        'session': 'session token here'
    }
)
print(response)
```