# Letterboxd api Bad Request (400) for no apparent reason python

Tags: python, api, rest

I'm trying to access the Letterboxd api to get an authentification token but I keep getting Bad Request feedback. Here's my code:

```
import requests
import urllib
import json

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}

url = 'https://api.letterboxd.com/api/v0/auth/token'

body = {
    'grant_type': 'password',
    'username': 'myname',
    'password': 'mypassword'
}

response = requests.post(
    url+urllib.parse.urlencode(headers), data=json.dumps(body))
print('\n')
print(response.text)
```

Any idea what I did wrong? The response is just an HTTP document with no info besides the Error message "400 Bad Request". Heres the documentation if it helps https://api-docs.letterboxd.com/#auth

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using headers with the Python requests library's get method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260457/using-headers-with-the-python-requests-librarys-get-method)

Comment: you send `headers` in URL but you have to send it as `headers=headers`

Comment: when you use mdoule `requests` then you can use `json=body` instead of `data=json.dumps(body)`

Answer (score 0):

First: I can't test if all code works.

You send `headers` in `url` but you should send it as part of `headers=`.

And when you use module `requests` then you can use `json=body` instead of `data=json.dumps(body)`

```
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)
```

But header `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` suggests that you will send data as `form` data, not `json` data - which needs `data=body` without converting to `json`

```
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=body)
```

---

**EDIT:**

In your [link to documentation](https://api-docs.letterboxd.com/#auth) I see link to [python module](https://pypi.org/project/letterboxd/) (in part `"Example implementations"`) - so maybe you should use it instead of writing own code because documentation mentionts something about `"All API requests must be signed"` (in part `"Request signing"`) - and this may need extra code to create it.